# Paypal Payments REST APIs - Error when adding platform fees

Tags: paypal, paypal-sandbox

I have a working request to the v2 api to create an order but as soon as I declare some platform fees I get these error messages in the response: 


**name**: 'UNPROCESSABLE_ENTITY',
**message**: 'The requested action could not be performed, semantically incorrect, or failed business validation.',
**debugID**: 96842ac321a3b
**details**: { issue: 'ACCOUNT_CANNOT_BE_FETCHED', description: 'ACCOUNT_CANNOT_BE_FETCHED' }

Does anyone know why this appends or how to fix this issue?

Comment: Ran into this issue in June when upgrading from V1 to V2.  Ending up having to contact PayPal support.  I don't know exactly how they fixed it but there was some permission issue associated with our account.  After they changed it on their end our calls started working.